# data not saving into database

Tags: php, android

Hi In the below code data not saving into database.In the file I am working with android.client side data coming correctly. from client side I am passing username,password,groupname,friendusername it will return array list.

Why I am not getting where i did mistake.

**php**

```
case "CreateGroup":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
            {               
                 $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];
                 $groupname = $_REQUEST['groupname'];

                 $sql = "select Id from users where username='".$friendUserName."' limit 1";

                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                             $requestId = $row->Id;
                             $groupname = $row->Id;

                             if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {
                                     $sql = "insert into group(providerId, requestId, groupname)
                                         values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".$groupname.")";
                                    echo $sql;

                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;  
                            }                                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }                               
                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }
            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: @Deena FAILED it's giving

Comment: did check following condition working or not "if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    $sql = "insert into group(providerId, requestId, groupname)values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".$groupname.")";

    to 

     $sql = mysql_query("insert into group(providerId, requestId, groupname)values('$userId','$requestId','$groupname')");

if ($sql)
    {
     $out = SUCCESSFUL;
     }
     else
     {
      $out = FAILED;
      }
```

Comment: then also giving FAILED

Comment: did you use "mysql_query("insert into group(providerId, requestId, groupname)values('$userId','$requestId','$groupname')")" ?

Comment: This condition is working or not if ($result = $db->query($sql)) . put inside testing echo

Comment: After this if line if i put echo means giving syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in  on line 217

Comment: $sql = "insert into group(providerId, requestId, groupname)values('$userId','$requestId','$groupname')";
          echo $sql;